# php looping a function and return result to original call

Tags: php, function, loops, return

I am having a tough time figuring this one out, any help?

I am passing some data into a looping function and want to return the result to the original call.

This only works if a result is found on the first loop, if the function calls itself again I get nothing returned. Though, if I echo the result I see that I have a match.

```
function fetchAllOffers () {

    /* do a bunch of things */

    $result = currentOffer($campaign, $campaignsArray); // <-- return result

    if ($result) {

        /* do more */

    }
}

function currentOffer ($step, $campaigns) {

    foreach ($campaigns as $c) {

        if (/* an exact match is found */) {

            return $c['id'];

        }

        elseif (/* half match move to next step */) {

            currentOffer($c, $campaigns);

        }
    }

    return $c['final']; // if no match found return

}
fetchAllOffers();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return result of `currentOffer()` in your function.

```
function currentOffer ($step, $campaigns)
{
    foreach ($campaigns as $c)
    {
        if (/* a match is found */)
            return $c['id'];
        else
            return currentOffer($c, $campaigns);
    }
}
```

Comment: Genius!! Thank you sir. couldn't wrap my head around that one, long night.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `currentOffer`. Also your loop is essentially useless in `currentOffer`, because you are repeatedly calling `currentOffer` until it returns a value. What you are doing is called recursion.

```
function currentOffer ($step, $campaigns) {

    //foreach ($campaigns as $c) {

        if (/* a match is found */) {

            return $c['id'];

        }

        else {

            $nextc = <something> // get the campaign following c here
            return currentOffer($nextc, $campaigns);

        }
    //}
}
```

Also when calling `currentOffer` again, you should pass in the next campaign, however it is you get it.

Comment: See my edit, but thank you the return was what I was looking for